# Is it correct to place the base to emitter resistor in a BJT circuit as follows?

Tags: transistors, relay, pulldown

This is a follow up Question to [What is use of R41 (base to emitter) resistor in Transistor Relay Circuit?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/378400/what-is-use-of-r41-base-to-emitter-resistor-in-transistor-relay-circuit)

My doubt is can we connect the resistor R41 between emitter of optocouler and GND?

The pulldown resistor is usually connected to one end of a switch. [image]

and it would be more consistent to connect R41 (in original schematic) to the emitter of optocoupler (SWITCH).

[image]

Comment: I think so too...

Answer (score 1):

While it looks superficially like a voltage divider, the voltage on the base of the transitor is constrained to the range 0 to 1V by the transistor itself. The value for this part is usually such that only a very small current flows through it.

The purpose of R41 is to prevent any current that leaks through the opto-coupler or the transistor C-B junction from biasing the transisor partly on and causing it to overheat.  20uA leakage mutiplied by worst-case beta or 300 is 6mA, at about 24V that's 144mW of heat generated in the transistor.

Answer (score 0):

The only reason I can think of for R41 to even exist is to add some threshold.  R3 and R41 creates a voltage divider, the transistor won't turn on until the voltage over R41 exceeds ~0.6V.

Moving the resistor to the new location would remove the threshold.  It could instead result in too little current flowing to the base.

Furthermore, there is no need for a pull-down resistor in this circuit.  If the input to the base is floating, it won't conduct.  If there is a long wire or a FET.